# async await Firebase cloud function has timeout when it contains three await lines

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

It seems that whenever I add a third await statement to my code, it causes the firebase function to timeout.

some tldr background:
I'm creating a push notifications server that has an admin back end that supports weekly recurring notifications. The cloud function is scheduled to run once per minute. It essentially performs this psuedo-code:

```
await: retrieve the list of notifications from the firebase database
if: any notifications have a timestamp that is at or before the current moment
    await: write a new rescheduled timestamp to the firebase database
    await: send out the notifications
return
```

If I comment out either of the second two awaits, the function executes completely in about 500ms, but whenever I run them together, the function runs to timeout (60 seconds)

Here's the complete function (typescript)

```js
export const heartbeat = functions.pubsub.schedule('*/1 * * * *').onRun(async event => {

  console.log("Yo, this v1.0.32 heart beats every minute!")
  const db = admin.firestore()

  // find topics with triggerTimes before or at the current time
  const timeTableSnapshot = await db.collection('fcmTimetable').where('triggerTime', '<=', moment().unix()).get()
  console.log('after timeTableSnapshot ' + timeTableSnapshot.docs.map(tts => tts.data().topic).join(', '))

  const datas = timeTableSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => [doc.ref, doc.data()]) as [FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference, FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData][]

  // check if the topic timetable entry is recurring, and update the targetTime accordingly,
  const batch = datas.reduce((batch, [docRef, data]) => {
    const {recurringWeekly, triggerTime, title, topic, message} = data
    if (recurringWeekly) {
      return batch.update(docRef, rescheduleNotifications(recurringWeekly, triggerTime, title, topic, message))
    } else {
      return batch.delete(docRef)
    }
  }, db.batch())
  console.log('batch created')
  await batch.commit().catch(err => console.log(err))
  console.log('batch committed')

  // send the messages
  const payloads = datas.map(([docRef, data]) => {
    return {
      notification: {
        title: data.title || 'Empty title yo!',
        body: data.message || 'Empty message yo!',
      },
      topic: data.topic,
    }
  })
  await admin.messaging().sendAll(payloads).catch(err => console.log(err))
  console.log('after sendAll')

  console.log('returning success')
  return 'success'
})
```

I expect the function to run both awaits sequentially in about one second without a timeout. Does anybody know what might cause the 60 second timeout? Is there a limit to how many awaits you can use in a firebase function?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This code is mixing async/await with then/catch callback in a very strange way.  Generally speaking, if you use async/await properly , you do not also need then/catch.  If this function is timing out, look into measuring the total time each asynchronous function takes (using log statemnts) and increasing the function's timeout if the default 60s is too short.

Comment: Wow, it really was that simple! I removed the catch from the end of sendAll and commit, and then everything worked as expected. I've been banging my head against this problem for a very long time. Thank you, Doug!